# Using flat structure vs wrapper

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

We have a function with the below contract, we have data as a wrapper and all user details are inside that other option where data is without wrapper. I would love your view which option would you prefer and why?

```
export interface IContactSource {
  id: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface IContactSearchAttempt {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  title: string;
  accountName: string;
  linkedinUrl?: string;
  source: IContactSource;
}

export enum ISearchAttemptOperation {
  "CONTACT_PROFILE" = "CONTACT_PROFILE",
  "ACCOUNT_PROFILE" = "ACCOUNT_PROFILE",
}


// first:
export interface ISearchAttemptBody {
  operation: ISearchAttemptOperation;
  data: IContactSearchAttempt;
  attempt?: number;
}

// second:
export interface ISearchAttemptBody {
  operation: ISearchAttemptOperation;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  title: string;
  accountName: string;
  linkedinUrl?: string;
  source: IContactSource;  
  attempt?: number;
}
```

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Answer (score 0):

If `ISearchAttemptBody` is a subtype of `IContactSearchAttempt`, and you have to use it as a supertype, use `extends`

```
interface ISearchAttemptBody extends IContactSearchAttempt {
  operation: ISearchAttemptOperation;
  attempt?: number;
}
function f(c: IContactSearchAttempt) {}
let b: ISearchAttemptBody = {...}
f(body)
```

Otherwise use a property

If the property may have multiple types, which can be used interchangeably, use generic property

```
export interface IGenericAttemptBody<T> {
  operation: ISearchAttemptOperation;
  data: T;
  attempt?: number;
}
```